# I have a Tab separated file in Unix which has data issue

Tags: perl, awk, gawk

I have to make sure each line has 4 columns, but the input data is quite a mess:

- The first line is header.
- The second line is valid as it has 4 columns.
- The third is also valid (it's ok if the description field is null)

ID field and "god bless me" Last column PNumber is are not null fields.

As one can see 4th line is messed up because of newline character in "Description column" it spanned across multiple lines.

```
ID  Name    Description Phnumber
1051    John    5674 I am doing good, is this task we need to fix   908342
1065    Rohit               9876246
10402   rob I am    
    doing good, 
    is this task we need to fix     908341
105552  "Julin rob hain"    i know what to do just let me do it     
    "
    "
    "
    "
    "
    " 
908452   1051   Dave    I am doing reporting this week  88889999
```

Maybe a screenshot will make it easier to see the problem

[image]

Each line will start with a number and ends with a number. Each line should have 4 columns.

desired output

```
ID      Name    Description                                         Phnumber
1051    John    5674 I am doing good, is this task we need to fix    908342
1065    Rohit                                                        9876246
10402   rob   I am doing good, 563 is this task we need to fix       908341
105552  "Julin rob hain" i know what to do just let me do it         908452   
1051    Dave    I am doing reporting this week                      88889999
```

The data is sample data the actual file has 12 columns. yes in between columns can have numbers and few are date fields (like 2017-03-02)

Comment: Is this an AI bot pretending?

Comment: @krivamsh I cleaned up your question a bit, but you should still **add the actual question you  want to ask**. Right now it only defines and illustrates the problem

Comment: There's a million ways we could produce 4 columns per line from your sample input. Post the associated expected output to give us a clue which permutation you actually want and at least tell us what the algorithm should be to identify columns even if you don't have your own code attempt to post (see [ask]).

Comment: I am sorry guys thought the header will give a clear idea

Comment: I have a file with TAB separated. The file in unstructured, i have to make sure that each line should have 4 columns and it should start with number because its represents ID field and ends with number because its phone number filed.

Its not a well defined file (I know at least ID is not null, not sure about the phone number).

Comment: Thanks for all you help. I am using Stackoverflow for the first time, now I got a feel of it.

thanks for the help greatly appreciated @fvu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick

cat file_name | perl -0pe 's/\n(?!([0-9]{6}|$)\t)//g' | perl -0pe 's/\r(?!([0-9]{6}|$)\t)//g' | sed '/^$/d'

Answer (score -1):

`awk` to the rescue!

assumes the all digit fields don't appear except first and last fields

```
awk 'NR==1; 
     NR>1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
             {if($i~/[0-9]+/) s=!s; printf "%s", $i (s?OFS:RS)}}' file


ID  Name    Description Phnumber
1051 John I am doing good, is this task we need to fix 908342
10423 rob I am doing good, is this task we need to fix 908341
1052 Julin rob hain i know what to do just let me do it " " " " " " 908452
1051 Dave I am doing reporting this week 88889999
```

perhaps set the `OFS` to `\t` to have more structure